# selenium youtube views stuck even using proxies

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, youtube, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to automate youtube to get views on videos. But it is stuck at a specific point.
I am using residential rotating proxies for each instance of chrome.,random user-agents, watching 90% above video but the views do not count at specific points. When I try to use it on other videos it counts for a specific time and then stops counting. Can you specify reasons for how to avoid the mistakes? I open 5 chrome at a time and each has a different proxy.